# 3D Touch: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Why is that `imageRef.data` is always `nil`? I had `imageRef.data` inside the peek function but it does not belongs there? It'll work when I peek (I assume the image starts to download) then when I press harder on the iPhone, the image would show. But most times I get `nil` error.

Now, I've moved that logic into the pop function and now it's always `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage

extension ExpenseFeedVC: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {

    // PEEK
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location),
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return nil}

        guard let expensePreview = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "expensePreviewVC") as? ExpensePreviewVC else {return nil }
        expensePreview.selectedItem = expenses[indexPath.row].type
        quickActionString = expenses[indexPath.row].type

        let imageUrl: String = expenses[indexPath.row].receiptUrl
        urlToPass = imageUrl

        expensePreview.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 150)

        previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame

        return expensePreview
    }

    // POP
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {

        if let rvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "receiptImagePreviewVC") as? ReceiptImagePreviewVC {

            let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: urlToPass)
            imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 2*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                print(data!)

            })

            rvc.poppedImage = self.imageToPass

            show(rvc, sender: self)

        }
    }
}
```

I took it out of "peek" because if I force touch quickly, I get an error. If I peek, wait few seconds, then press harder, I see the image. Where is best to put `imageRef.data` and why `data` is `nil` (inside the pop function)?

`urlToPass` returns the correct image url, always.

Answer (score 0):

Classic issue with async programming--the download hasn't happened immediately, which is why it works when you wait a few seconds. You need to do this instead:

```
let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: urlToPass)
imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 2*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
  // Check for an error
  ...
  // Prepare to switch to the next VC once the file has downloaded
  rvc.poppedImage = UIImage(data: data!)
  show(rvc, sender: self)
})
```